# Pass input value and add and subtract over it in angular

Tags: html, angular

I need to pass the amount, for example 94, to the input of add and subtract so that I add or subtract from that amount and not from zero.

[image: counter to zero]

My html:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let item of articulos">
              <td>{{item.articulo}}</td>
              <td>{{item.cantidad}}</td>
              <td>
                <input id="quantity" type="button" value="-" (click)="quantity=quantity-1">
                <input type="text" id="quantity2" name="quantity" value="{{quantity}}">
                <input id="quantity" type="button" value="+" (click)="quantity=quantity+1">
              </td>
            </tr>
```

My ts:

```
quantity: number;

  constructor(private datosService: DatosService) {
    this.quantity = 0;
    }
```

I need 94 and 60 to appear where it puts zero on the counter and to be able to add and subtract.

I have tried to change quantity to {{item.quantity}} in the following line and the values ​​are passed but it won't let me add and subtract on the value since the operation would no longer be done on quantity.

Comment: The way you do is incorrect. As all items share the same `quantity` variable, thus share the same value for addition/deduction. What you can do is in each `item` object has its own `quantity` property. With this, the addition/deduction will apply to the item selected, but not affect to others.

Comment: And how would that be?

Answer (score 0):

A more complete description of what Yong Shun is saying:

Right now, your component, as a whole, has a single `quantity` variable.

Your template, in its entirety, is referencing this one variable.

However, your template is rendering multiple rows (`*ngFor="let item of articulos"`).

Each of those rows (`item`) have their OWN quantity value (`item.cantidad`), but each of those rows point to exactly the same, single `quantity` variable.

So if you press `+` on the first row, `quantity` becomes 1. If you press `+` on  the *second* row, `quantity` becomes 2.

Many rows ---> one `quantity` variable.

You need one row -> one quantity variable.

You can either :

1. Extend your `item` objects with an extra property that you initialise and then use in the template, e.g.

```js
private onDataReceived(articulos: any[]): void {
    articulos.forEach((item: any) => {
        item.variableQuantity = item.cantidad;
    });

    this.articulos = articulos;
}
```

(Also, it's a button, why not use a `button` element?)

```html
<button (click)="item.variableQuantity+=1">+</button>
<input type="text" [value]="item.variableQuantity">
<button (click)="item.variableQuantity-=1">-</button>
```

OR

You keep track of the quantities separately (still needs to be initialised):

```js
public quantities = {};

private onDataReceived(articulos: any[]): void {
    articulos.forEach((item: any) => {
        quantities[item.articulo] = item.cantidad;
    });

    this.articulos = articulos;
}
```

```html
<button (click)="quantities[item.articulo]+=1">+</button>
<input type="text" [value]="quantities[item.articulo]">
<button (click)="quantities[item.articulo]-=1">-</button>
```

Comment: In the end I did it in another way, but thank you very much for the contribution